# What's the difference between a static AI and a dynamic AI?

Tags: terminology

I recently watched a YouTube video (sorry, can't remember the link) where (a very talented) someone created what they called a *"static AI"*.

Somewhere in the video they said something along the lines of:

> *"this is a static AI, it's very simple and not dynamic at all"*

What does this mean? What's the difference between a static AI and a dynamic AI?

Comment: Hi! This may be non-standard terminology, or it may refer to static/dynamic enviroments, or static/dynamic training in machine learning, or who knows what else. It is really hard to judge without context, therefore in order to receive an adequate answer you should find that link, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My sense is they're probably talking about the difference between symbolic AI (aka [GOFAI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_artificial_intelligence))  and learning algorithms.

GOFAI typically uses [heuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic), which are static—essentially fixed rules governing decision making.

Statistical AI, aka [Machine Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning), is dynamic and can analyze and evaluate the environment to form its own decision rules.

Sometimes a trained NN that is no longer learning is said to have created it's own heuristics.